# CSS transition on removeClass

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a slide effect to a div with css transitions, but apparently the transition works only on close.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider closed" id="more-details"> Some content </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .8s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.2, 1);
}

.slider.closed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.slider.opened {
  max-height: 10000px;
}
```

JS:

```
    $('.read-more').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).toggle();

        $('#more-details').removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');

        $('#read-less').show();

   });

   $('.read-less').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#more-details').addClass('closed').removeClass('opened');

        $('#read-more').toggle();
   });
```

As said: the div open and close, but the transition is performed only on close...any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using a transition on max-height because you don't know the exactly final height your content could be, right?

Anyway, you simply can't animate from max-height:0 to max-height equals to a enormous value. Coming back instead, is possibile, because the height is known.

Generally, for this type of animation I use somenthing like this.

- I wrap the content in a div with `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;`
- On click, I use jQuery to calculate the exactly height of the content div with `$('selector').height();`
- Use jQuery to set this value on the parent of my content `$('wrapper').height(value);`

The CSS transition style will do the animation trick.